# FontAwesome images appear as squares

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

Just started using font-awesome and all my images appear as squares if I use the font-awesome css locally. My code is straightforward:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.css"/>

</head>
<i class="fa fa-truck"></i>truck
```

I put the font files in ../fonts/ as it says in the font-awesome.css. I also put the fa which is particular to version 4.0, and I also tried the CDN. However, with the CDN, I don't even get a square, I just get a blank. Anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you viewing the page as a file right off the disk, or are you viewing it locally through a web server? Depending on your browser, it may be considering the font asset's location a different origin, and may have a strict origin policy. Check the network pane of your browser's dev tools and see what the request is and what the server responds with.

Comment: Try viewing source, and clicking on the link your <link href=""> gives. If it returns 404, you then know your directory is wrong.